# The limit of a product to infinity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

What is the difficulty with this question to Mathematica? Is it just a problem with Mathematica v.8.0
or all versions are in trouble with it? Or is something wrong with my input?

```
Limit[Product[(1 + t/n^3)^(1/t^(1/3)), {n, 1, Infinity}],  t -> Infinity]
```

Comment: it's running for a long period of time is your problem ?

Comment: It's running for a long period of time and gives no answer (1 hour is it OK?). The limit has a closed form though.

Comment: Instead of using infinity use a large number you shall get quite relevant result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I replaced `t -> u^3`, `t^(1/3) -> u` as a manual simplification.  Then I got

```
Product[(1 + u^3/n^3)^(1/u), {n, 1, Infinity}]
(* (1/(Gamma[1 + u] Gamma[1 - u/2 - 1/2 I Sqrt[3] u] * 
    Gamma[1 - u/2 + 1/2 I Sqrt[3] u]))^(1/u) *)

Limit[
  (1/(Gamma[1 + u] Gamma[1 - u/2 - 1/2 I Sqrt[3] u] * 
      Gamma[1 - u/2 + 1/2 I Sqrt[3] u]))^(1/u),
  u -> Infinity]
(* E^((2 \[Pi])/Sqrt[3]) *)
```

Now `Product` returned a value for both forms of input (simplified and unsimplified).  But the limit of the product (of the unsimplified input) takes forever.  (Tested on V9.0.1 and V8.0.4.)

Comment: Hmmm... without using simplifications I obtained:               
  
 `(1/(Gamma[1 + t^(1/3)] Gamma[1/2 (2 + (-1 - I Sqrt[3])t^(1/3))] Gamma[
   1/2 (2 + I (I + Sqrt[3]) t^(1/3))]))^(1/t^(1/3))`

Comment: @NikolaDimitrov  Yes, that's what I got.  But finding the `Limit` of it takes forever.  One can simplify before or after finding the `Product`.  Edited to clarify (I hope).

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for your job (+1)

Comment: The expression Gamma[1-u/2-1/2 I Sqrt[3] u]*Gamma[1-u/2+1/2 I Sqrt[3] u] 
has a real value and can be simplified as Abs[Gamma[1-u/2+1/2 I Sqrt[3] u]]^2

Comment: @VaclavKotesovec Yes, but interestingly, from the point of view of computing limits in *Mathematica*, expressions in `Abs` are less simple.  `Limit` will use `Series` if it can, I believe, but `Abs` is not complex-differentiable, so `Limit` must do something else.  Computing the limit with the `Abs` expression takes a lot longer (tested in V10.1).